# Excel Charts Data Range Reference

Tags: excel, charts

I have a workbook with many tabs, all of which are identical in format. I want to have the same embedded charts in each worksheet. I can't seem to copy the charts from one tab to other tabs without the new data range being tied to the original worksheet tab name. My first choice is to refer to the data range as B6:B87 or =B6:B87 WITHOUT the reference being ='TabName'!B6:B87, but Excel doesn't seem to allow it.

Comment: u can record a macro and run it on each of ur sheet using record macro wizard

Answer (score 1):

Copy the entire sheet, including chart and data. The copied chart links to the data range on the copied sheet. Now replace the original data on the copied sheet with the new data. The copied chart links to the new data on the copied sheet.

Answer (score 0):

Make copy's of the data range on the same page than cut it and past it on the page you want.it wont have the sheet name where it was copied.